# Fractal Transform nested array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a hierarchical array which has the parent child relation. Now when I try to transform it, the transformation is happening only on one level. My array looks like following :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent_uuid] => 
            [name] => Users
            [placement] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [parent_uuid] => 4
                            [name] => User Profile
                            [placement] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [parent_uuid] => 1
                                            [name] => Test Page
                                            [placement] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am using fractal transformers, but the problem is after transforming, I am getting only the first children as the transformers will not look into the nested array. How can I make the transformer look into nested array ?

Comment: Are you using collection method of the transformer or item?

Comment: Yes. I am using collection method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using default includes. We need to have the children as `default includes` in the first tree transformer and should do the same in Child transformer also.